# Unity Breakpoint Debugging on Mac M1 does not detect iPad

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, debugging, ipad, apple-m1

I'm trying to setup my debugging pipeline to test my game on the iPad, but when I try to attach Visual Studio the iPad is not shown in VS. Interestingly the iPad is actually shown in the Unity Console when connected using a USB cable, and XCode both via USB and Wifi.

'Till now I failed to find propper instructions on how to fix this problem.

> - Mac Studio M1 Ultra
> - MacOS 13.0.1 (22A400)
> - Unity 2020.3.39f (intel); Unity 2022.2.0f1 (silicon)
> - XCode Version 14.1 (14B47b)
> - Visual Studio for Mac 17.4.1 (build 28)
> - iPad (10th Generation)
> - iPadOS 16.0; iPadOS 16.1.1

---

**UPDATE:**
There seems to be an issue with iOS 16, as [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-attach-visual-studio-to-ios-device.579565/) discussion in the unity-forum suggests. I checked that an an older iPhone with iOS 14.4 in indeed detected. Anyway, no solution to that problem yet...

---

**ANOTHER UPDATE:** Corresponding ticket on the Unity Issue Page:
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/managed-debugger-does-not-work-on-ios-16

[image: XCode connected via Wifi]
[image: iPad waiting for Debugger]
[image: empty list of debuggers in xcode]